# How to find different occurrences of a substring in a string using regex?

Tags: java, regex, expression, substring

Basically what I want to do is this:

```
String mystr = "hello Benjamin Benny Benn hey hey";
String pattern = "Be";
```

Desired list = {"Benjamin","Benny","Benn"};

I know how to do this in a really simple way. What I am looking for is a fast way to do it based on regex or whatever that works for me. I want a list of all sub-strings(words) starting with a specific pattern.

Comment: `I know how to do this in a really simple way.` So please post your code to make your question more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex:

```
Be\w+
```

## What it does?

It matches all the words that start with `Be`

If you want word starting with anything else, simply do this:

```
String startsWith="Be"; // change this to match your requirements

String regexPattern=startsWith+"\\w+"; //escaped backslash
```

Now, you can substitute anything in `startsWith`, so you can match words that starts with a specific string.

**Note:** You'll need to escape the backslash in java. So `\` becomes `\\`

Comment: Explanation will be very helpful for OP.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Done. I've explained

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how can I use this so it gives me a list of all words. like an array of strings. Is there a specific method or something?

Comment: You can use myString.matches(regexPattern) to test that. You will have to create the list by looping through each string in the input and testing if the pattern matches. If you are using the Commons Collections, you can use CollectionUtils.filter(list, predicate). See https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#filter(java.util.Collection, org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate)

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
String mystr = "hello Benjamin Benny Benn hey hey";
String pattern = "Be";
for(String str : mystr.split("\\s")){
    if(str.matches(pattern+"\\w+")){
         System.out.println("Matched "+str);
         // Add the str to list
    }
}
```

Here,

`\\w+` indicates - 
word characters `(a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)` (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible))

`\\s` indicates - 
 whitespace `(\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")`

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer which helped me a lot:

```
String yourString = "hi #how are # you";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("#\\s*(\\w+)").matcher(yourString);    
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

This way even if your pre-string is separated from the main string it works fine.